# Normal Distribution Plot by name from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe like below:

```
dateTime        Name    DateTime        day seconds zscore
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 15:17 james   11/1/2016 15:17 Tue 55020   1.158266091
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:41 james   11/1/2016 13:41 Tue 49260   -0.836236954
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 13:42 james   11/1/2016 13:42 Tue 49320   -0.81546088
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:07  matt    11/1/2016 9:07  Tue 32820   -0.223746683
11/1/2016 9:08  matt    11/1/2016 9:08  Tue 32880   -0.111873342
11/1/2016 9:48  matt    11/1/2016 9:48  Tue 35280   4.363060322
```

zscore is calculated as below:

```
grp2 = df.groupby(['Name'])['seconds']
df['zscore'] = grp2.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std(ddof=1))
```

I would like to plot my data in a bell curve / normal distribution plot and save this as a picture/pdf file for each Name in my dataframe.

I have tried to plot the zscores like below:

```
df['by_name'].plot(kind='hist', normed=True)
range = np.arange(-7, 7, 0.001)
plt.plot(range, norm.pdf(range,0,1))
plt.show()
```

How would I go about plotting the by_name zscores column for each name in my data?

Comment: When you say you "tried to plot the zscores like below", what is the result, in how far is the outcome not what you expect and what exactly would you expect instead?

Comment: The result shows the plotting of the zscore column as a whole not grouped by the username. Essentially, I would like to see 4 different plots with the data i have above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Name='matt joe adam farley'.split() * 100,
        Seconds=np.random.randint(4000, 5000, 400)
    ))

df['Zscore'] = df.groupby('Name').Seconds.apply(lambda x: x.div(x.mean()))

df.groupby('Name').Zscore.plot.kde()
```

[image]

---

***split out plots***

```
g = df.groupby('Name').Zscore
n = g.ngroups
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n // 2, 2, figsize=(6, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, (name, group) in enumerate(g):
    r, c = i // 2, i % 2
    group.plot.kde(title=name, ax=axes[r, c])
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

***`kde` + `hist`***

```
g = df.groupby('Name').Zscore
n = g.ngroups
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n // 2, 2, figsize=(6, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, (name, group) in enumerate(g):
    r, c = i // 2, i % 2
    a1 = axes[r, c]
    a2 = a1.twinx()
    group.plot.hist(ax=a2, alpha=.3)
    group.plot.kde(title=name, ax=a1, c='r')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: How would you represent this when there's potentially thousands of names?

Comment: You have to choose.  You asked for separate plots.  Do you want thousands of plots?  Or do you want to group by say every `n` names?

Comment: @johnnyb can you provide an actual data set?