# Calculate win rates depending on game duration with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames that looks like this:

```
   match_id hero_name    won
0         0    Rubick   True
1         9    Rubick  False
2        16    Rubick  False
3        28    Rubick   True
4        37    Rubick   True

   match_id  duration
0         0      2375
1         1      2582
2         2      2716
3         3      3085
4         4      1887
```

And I'm trying to calculate the win percentage by game length of each hero. So far I calculated the percentage for buckets of 5 minutes each, but I can't find a way to plot a curve that fits the points I calculated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
matches = pd.merge(a, b, on='match_id')
matches['lost'] = ~matches['won']
# Ther's a single match with over 16000s, the others are all less than 6673
matches = matches[matches.duration < 7000]
# From 50s to 7000s with 5 minutes steps
ranges = np.arange(50, 7000, 300)

# Group by hero_name and duration range and count won and lost games
g = matches.groupby(['hero_name', pd.cut(matches.duration, ranges)]).sum()
# Win percentage
g['win_p'] = g['won'] / (g['won'] + g['lost'])
# Drop other columns and fills some NaN
g = g[['win_p']]
g = g.fillna(0)
g = g.reset_index()
g = g.groupby('hero_name')
n = g.ngroups
```

But I don't know how to plot a curve. I've tried the `kde()` but it only counts victories and not a win rate and if I use it on the already calculated percentages I get the sum of them. How can I interpolate a curve and plot the win rate depending on the duration for each hero?

Comment: This can be plot by subplot , btw I like rubick a lot in dota :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need unstack here , more info look at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

```
g.win_p.unstack(level=0).plot( subplots=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've managed to plot something out of it though it's still not the curve I'm trying to plot. I'd like to get something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768629/normal-distribution-plot-by-name-from-pandas-dataframe) but I want to use the percentage with the buckets I calculated instead of what is done in the linked question.

Comment: @CostaM what you need is try to fill NaN ?

Comment: No, I managed to fill them and to plot like you said, but I'm trying to plot a curve that fit the points and not a segmented line